# Apply new design style for iOS 8?

Tags: ios8, size-classes

iOS 8 introduces size classes for designing different devices. As showed in images, iPad size classes values are always regular. The question is that it will be different UI for iPad in portrait and in landscape, but its height, for example, is always regular height, how can I know to apply different UI?